# Comparing stabilization of stable category modulo injectives and a Verdier localization

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-categories, limits-and-colimits, triangulated-categories, abelian-categories

Let $\mathcal A$ be an abelian category with enough injectives. Let $\mathcal I$ be the collection of injective objects. Let $\mathcal A/\mathcal I$ be the quotient category whose objects are same as those of $\mathcal A$ and morphisms are $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal A/\mathcal I}(X,Y)/R_{X,Y}$, where $R_{X,Y}$, where $R_{X,Y}$ is the collection of all morphisms factoring through some object of $\mathcal I$. It is well-known that $\mathcal A/\mathcal I$ has a natural right triangulated structure, see Theorem 2.12(ii) of Beligiannis–Marmaridis 1994 ([DOI link](https://doi.org/10.1080/00927879408825119)). Consider the stabilization $S(\mathcal A/\mathcal I)$ as defined in Remark 3.2 of Beligiannis 2000 ([DOI link](https://doi.org/10.1080/00927870008827105)).

My question is: I wonder if there is an analogue of Theorem 3.8 of Beligiannis 2000 (previous link) in the above setting? In particular, I wonder if $S(\mathcal A/\mathcal I) \cong D^b(\mathcal A)/K^b(\mathcal I)$ ?

Comment: I guess the answer is *no* because $D^b(\mathcal A)/K^b(\mathcal I)$ is triangulated while $S(\mathcal A/\mathcal I)$ is merely right triangulated.

Comment: @LeoAlonso: The stabilization of any right/left triangulated category is triangulated ...

Comment: Do you assume your category $\mathcal{A}$ is Frobenius?

Comment: @LeoAlonso: No I do not .... If $\mathcal A$ were Frobenius, then  $S(\mathcal A/\mathcal I)\cong \mathcal A/\mathcal I$ which is then just $D_{sg}(\mathcal A)$ I think ...

Comment: Oh, I see your $S$ denotes stabilization, sorry for the misunderstanding. I am afraid I do not have intuition about this.

Comment: @LeoAlonso: that is fine ... thank you for taking an interest :)

Answer (score 3):

This follows by applying Theorem 3.8 of Beligiannis' 2000 paper to the opposite
categories.

$\mathcal{I}$ is a full additive subcategory of $\mathcal{A}$, closed under
direct summands. It is covariantly finite, since $\mathcal{A}$ has enough
injectives, and every $\mathcal{I}$-monic has a cokernel in $\mathcal{A}$, since
$\mathcal{A}$ is abelian.

So $\mathcal{I}^{op}$ is a full contravariantly finite additive subcategory of
$\mathcal{A}^{op}$, closed under direct summands, and every
$\mathcal{I}^{op}$-epic has a kernel in $\mathcal{A}^{op}$.

But these are precisely the hypotheses of Theorem 3.8, so that theorem gives a
triangulated equivalence
$$S(\mathcal{A}^{op}/\mathcal{I}^{op})\simeq
K^{-,b}(\mathcal{I}^{op})/K^{b}(\mathcal{I}^{op}),$$
where the left hand side is the stabilization of a left triangulated category.

But the left hand side is just $S(\mathcal{A}/\mathcal{I})^{op}$ (the
stabilization of a right triangulated category), and the right hand side is just
$\left(K^{+,b}(\mathcal{I})/K^{b}(\mathcal{I})\right)^{op}$, so there is a
triangulated equivalence
$$S(\mathcal{A}/\mathcal{I})\simeq K^{+,b}(\mathcal{I})/K^{b}(\mathcal{I})
\simeq D^{b}(\mathcal{A})/K^{b}(\mathcal{I}).$$

Comment: I guess the only non-trivial part for me is why $S(\mathcal A^{op}/\mathcal I^{op})\cong S(\mathcal A/\mathcal I)^{op}$ ... will think about it

Comment: @SnakeEyes If it’s not clear from the construction of the stabilization of a left/right triangulated category $\mathcal{T}$, it should be clear from the universal property of the functor $\mathcal{T}\to S(\mathcal{T})$.